# How to wait SQL request in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have function `connect():` that connects to DB and does request.

Also there is function `output():` that iterate all are selected rows.

```
connect():

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

            result = cur.fetchall()

            for record in result:
                print(record[11])
                url.append(record[11])
```

At first I call:

```
connect()
```

After

```
output()
```

Will function `output()` still `connect()` runs query and fills array `url`?

Or function `output()` will have all response from db (url)?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

Put connect() in a try/catch and read the table in else:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott',
                                database='testt')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  # Read your table
  cnx.close()
```

Comment: What was changed?

Comment: The `else` part will be executed once the connection was done, if it could connect before some timeout. You can define the timeout in `connect()` w/ the `connect_timeout` keyword